# Rails 3.1 app using gem spine_rails (0.0.9)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, spine.js

I created rails3.1 app in spine.js using spine_rails (0.0.9) gem and eco gem.  I created two `spine:scaffold` in my rails app to relate `has_many`, `belongs_to` relationship.  I included `hasMany`, `belongs_to` in `spine:model`.

I don't know how to get id from one `spine:scaffold` to another `spine:scaffold`.